# Show input field names from Java Map while mapping to new JSON object in Dataweave

Tags: java, csv, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 with Mule 3.8.1 and I have a csv file that I have converted to java using Dataweave.  Later in the workflow I have to perform a new mapping to the output JSON object using Dataweave.

I have a number of fields to map so wanted to find out if there is there a way of showing the fields in the Java input in the left side input panel so I can use the graphical GUI to map?

The code I am using to convert the csv to java in Dataweave is:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/csv
%output application/java
---
payload
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to define metadata in configuration of transform component.

Follow the sequence

1. Click on define metdata

   [image: Click on define metadata]
2. Add type id (any name)

   [image: Add type id any name]
3. Select type.

   [image: Select type]
4. Select java object type.

   [image: Select java object type]
5. Type qualified name of class.

   [image: Find your class]

Answer (score 0):

To add to Beacon's response..after you follow those instructions you can right click on the payload -> Edit Sample Data and then add your sample/mock up java object info following

The input java class (follows TheBeacon's instructions):

```
package org.example;
    public class Name {
       String first;
       String last;

    public Name() {};

    public void setFirst(String first){
       this.first = first;
    }
    public void getFirst(){
       return first;
    }
    public setLast(String last){
       this.last = last;
    }

    public getLast() {
      return last;
    }
    }
```

Then your DW input side example would look like:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    first: 'Jane',
    last: 'Doe'    
} as :object {
    class : "org.example.Name"
}
```